# Get Data With cURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

```
$args = array(
'access_token' => 'xxxxxxx'
); 
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";

 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

This Is My code to Get My Friends
Below Is Expected Output. Where I Wll get All My friends Name And id.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
  "name": "xxxx", 
  "id": "xxxx"
}, 
{
  "name": "xxxx", 
  "id": "xxxx"
},
```

But Its Giving Error.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) ","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Answer (score 0):

100 means Invalid parameter. [This should help you](http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html) diagnose other error codes as you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use facebook latest SDK and this is not proper way to get output
You have to use something like below code

```
$queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends')
);
// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
try{
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
}catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
```

Include Facebook SDK file change your key and try above code

Comment: I Dont Want To get My friends through SDk but accesstoken